# How to download a file using google drive link?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am developing an application in which I want to download a file that is saved in the google drive. I have to link associated with the file. The link look like this `https://docs.google.com/.....` . How can i download this file by giving it the default name and mime type?

Comment: Could you describe in better detail what you tried so far?

Comment: I am able to download the file using download manager if i can give a file name and extension. But what I want is to download the file and save it with the  filename and extension it had when it was uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

Easy. I would use [google drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk)

Ex:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

There are examples in different programming languages on the [Download Files section](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads).

And you need to create an [access token](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth) to use the API.